# Player rises indefinitely

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason, the player character (Xeno) just floats off into space when I run the game. I was trying to make them jump. Please help! I'm using Visual Studio and Unity 2D (Ver. 2021.3.16f1)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class XenoController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const float V = 0f;
    public float speed = 10f;
    public float jumpspeed = 15f;
    private float direction = 0;
    private Rigidbody2D Xeno;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()

    {
        Xeno = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        direction = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (direction > 0f) {
            Xeno.velocity = new Vector2(direction * speed, Xeno.velocity.y);
        }
        else if (direction < 0f)
        {
            Xeno.velocity = new Vector2(direction * speed, Xeno.velocity.y);
        }
        else
        {
            Xeno.velocity = new Vector2(0, Xeno.velocity.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) ;
        {
            Xeno.velocity = new Vector2(Xeno.velocity.x, jumpspeed);
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting the player to jump and now this is driving me insane

Comment: Where do you believe you have implemented a jump?  Once you set the Y velocity, you never change it.  If you want gravity, then you have to implement it, by reducing the Y velocity over time.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Roberts pointed out, you never change the Y velocity back. Make sure gravity scale is on in you rigidbody 2d, I also recommend adding some logic to prevent Xeno from jumping while already in the air. I tend to use OnCollisionEnter2D and related functions for this.